# Disable update post button after submit keeps the post as a draft

Tags: wordpress

I have a form in WordPress that has a dynamically generated text box so the user can enter multiple text boxes. This works fine but if the user presses the save/update button multiple times it is saving multiples of the same data from these generated text boxes.

I tried a JavaScript solution to disable the button once pressed which works, my data saves correctly from the generated text boxes but then if it is a new post only it ever saves as a draft.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using disable on the `#publish` button, `.hide();` worked instead.